# Array Argument Desctructuring throws unexpected error

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Was trying out node 6.9.0 and wrote the following example:

```
'use strict'

function hello (opts) {
  let [ firstName, lastName, age ] = opts
  console.log(`Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}. Glad you're feeling ${age}`)
}
hello({})
```

The result I got was:

```
/Users/hiphipjorge/runnable/blog-posts/november-2016/index.js:6
  let [ firstName, lastName, age ] = opts
                                     ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at hello (/Users/hiphipjorge/runnable/blog-posts/november-2016/index.js:6:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hiphipjorge/runnable/blog-posts/november-2016/index.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

What is the `undefined` function the error is referring to? Could I provide an interface array to any object for array destructuring?

Comment: Are you passing an options object to the function hello and then use array destructuring?

Comment: Yeah, which is totally intentional. Want to have array descturing for non-arrays. See answer below. Purely hipothetical :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an iterator generator (`*[Symbol.iterator]()`) to your object in order for this to work.

```
'use strict'

class KindaSortaLikeAnArray {
  *[Symbol.iterator](){
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
  }
}

function hello (opts) {
  let [ firstName, lastName, age ] = opts
  console.log(`Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}. Glad you're feeling ${age}`)
}
hello(new KindaSortaLikeAnArray())
```

This iterator can go through the keys of an object in the following way:

```
'use strict'

var obj = {
  hello: 'world',
  wow: 'great',
  a: 'b'
}
obj[Symbol.iterator] = function*(){
  let keys = Object.keys(this)
  for (let key of keys) {
    yield this[key]
  }
}

function hello (opts) {
  let [ firstName, lastName, age ] = opts
  console.log(`Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}. Glad you're feeling ${age}`)
}
hello(obj)
```